# How to initialize a multi-dimensional array of unknown array length

Tags: java, android

I am getting problems when generating a multi-dimensional array with unknown size. How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 8):

To generate a multi-dimensional array with unknown size is called a jagged array.

For example:

```
String[][] array = new String[5][];
```

Java uses arrays of arrays for multi-dimensional arrays. I think you have to specify the first size. Otherwise, use list of lists.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

Comment: I am unable to use the following links for the above mentioned problem.  http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/collections-generics/6838-how-declare-object-multi-dimension-array.html

Comment: Then i do not think its impossible to be able to set a completly dynamic array you will have to use the first example provided.

Answer (score 2):

Array is static. ArrayList is dynamic.

Before creating an array you should be aware of the size of the array. To create a multidimensional array without knowing array size is not possible.

Better you have to use a nested `ArrayList` or nested `Vector`:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

Comment: Hello Deepak, I have used ArrayList and with the following link. http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/collections-generics/6838-how-declare-object-multi-dimension-array.html    but unable to run is successfully.

Comment: That is not true. You can generate each dimension on its own. This prints a nice triangle: `int dim1 = 6;
int[][] array = new int[dim1][];
for (int i = 0; i < dim1; ++i)
    array[i] = new int[i + 1];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array[i]));`